# Circle in a complex plane.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Let $C$ be a circle in the complex plane, and let $x$ be a fixed, non-zero complex number. Prove that $\{xz : z \in C\}$ is also a circle.

I would really appreciate any help that would get me started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition

$$C=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z-a|=r\,\,,\,\,a\in\Bbb C\,,\,\,0<r\in\Bbb R\}=\{z=a+re^{it}\;;\;0\leq t\leq 2\pi\}$$

Now, putting $\,x=Re^{i\theta}\,$ , we get

$$\,\{xz\;;\;z\in C\}=\{xa+rRe^{i(t+\theta)}\;;\;0\leq t\leq 2\pi\}$$

which is a circle, too.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that multiplication of a complex number is really a rotation and a dilation. More explicitly, if you write the circle and $x$ in polar form then what do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $|\cdot|$ denotes the norm of a complex number, then for $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ we have $|zw|=|z|\cdot|w|$.  Since $x$ is fixed it has a fixed norm.  Now think about the definition of a circle: every point in the circle will have the same norm, right?  Do you see how the result follows?